# Unclear response from cron

Tags: php, shell, cron

I'm not sure how to debug this issue - I'm trying to run a job from cron.  The specification is:

```
CRON_MODE=1 /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/public_html/_live/shop/admin/cron_backup.php
```

When the job runs, I get this response by email from CPanel Cron:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `0'
sh: -c: line 0: `exit(0)'
```

I have verified the contents of cron_backup.php, and I have verified the path to that file.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the code, we see no [tag:php], [tag:shell] or [tag:cron] code and the problem is caused by syntax in your code.

Comment: Line 0 is <?php. I have syntax checked and run the cron_backup.php script so I don't think that's it - but I will post the file.

Comment: I think this message is a response from a failed mysqldump.